# Working With Monochrome QImage

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am trying to extract a bitmask from a QPixmap and pass it to OpenCV.  My bitmask is created by "painting" operations.

My process so far has been:

1. Create a `QPixmap,` `QPixmap::fill(QColor(0,0,0,0))` and use a `QPainter` with `QPainter::setPen(QColor(255,0,0,255))` to `QPainter::drawPoint(mouse_event->pos()`
2. When ready to extract the bitmask `QPixmap::toImage()` then `QImage::createAlphaMask()`, which is documented to return `QImage::Format_MonoLSB`

I am now officially stuck though.  I'm having trouble deciphering the documentation:

> Each pixel stored in a QImage is represented by an integer. The size of the integer varies depending on the format. QImage supports several image formats described by the Format enum.
>
> Monochrome images are stored using 1-bit indexes into a color table with at most two colors. There are two different types of monochrome images: big endian (MSB first) or little endian (LSB first) bit order.
>
> ...
>
> The createAlphaMask() function builds and returns a 1-bpp mask from the alpha buffer in this image...

Also:

> QImage::Format_MonoLSB  --- 2 ---The image is stored using 1-bit per pixel. Bytes are packed with the less significant bit (LSB) first.

Could anyone help me clarify how to transfer this into a cv::Mat.

Also, am I supposed to read this that each pixel will be an `unsigned char` or will we be storing 8 pixels in a bit.

Comment: I was confused on how to work with it.  Extract data from it, and move it to a cv::Mat.  But I used the memory analyzer to examine the output.  I'm going to post up a method in a second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've successfully managed to transfer a monochrome QImage to a cv::Mat.  I hope the following code is helpful to others:

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** There was a major bug with this code.  **`bytesPerLine` is byte aligned as well as word aligned on some machines.  Thus the width() should be used with cur_byte**

```
QImage mask; //Input from wherever
cv::Mat workspace;
if(!mask.isNull() && mask.depth() == 1)
{
    if(mask.width() != workspace.cols || mask.height() != workspace.rows)
        workspace.create(mask.height(), mask.width(), CV_8UC1);

    for(int i = 0; i < mask.height(); ++i)
    {
        unsigned char * cur_row = mask.scanLine(i);
        //for(int cur_byte = 0, j = 0; cur_byte < mask.bytesPerLine(); ++cur_byte) wrong
        for(int cur_byte = 0, j = 0; j < mask.width(); ++cur_byte)
        {
            unsigned char pixels = cur_row[cur_byte];
            for(int cur_bit = 0; cur_bit < 8; ++cur_bit, ++j)
            {
                if(pixels & 0x01) //Least Significant Bit
                    workspace.at<unsigned char>(i, j) = 0xff;
                else
                    workspace.at<unsigned char>(i, j) = 0x00;
                 pixels = pixels >> 1; //Least Significant Bit
            }
        }
     }
 }
```