# cv:::Mat clone Segfault

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am getting a segfault when cloning a `cv::Mat`.  Two functions are called, and work on `m_mask` a member variable (not a pointer) of my class:

Set the mask:

```
void SetMask(QImage mask)
{
    if(!mask.isNull() && mask.depth() == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Mask width: " << mask.width() << " and mask height: " << mask.height() << std::endl << std::flush;
        if(mask.width() != m_mask.cols || mask.height() != m_mask.rows)
            m_mask.create(mask.height(), mask.width(), CV_8UC1);

        if(m_mask.data == 0)
            std::cout << "MALLOC FAILED" << std::endl << std::flush;

        //Copy data here

        cv::imshow("OpenCV Image", m_mask);
    }
    else
        m_mask = cv::Scalar(0);
}
```

Then use the mask:

```
QString MaskToXML()
{
    QString xml_out;
    if(!m_mask.empty())
    {
        cv::Mat workspace = m_mask.clone(); //Clone our mask - SEGFAULT HERE

        //Run the contour code
        std::vector< std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
        cv::findContours(workspace, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        //do stuff
    }
    return xml_out;
}
```

Comment: What did the debugger say?

Comment: That's the worst part, I can't find any information from the debugger.  I compiled OpenCV and didn't compile it with debug symbols...  ACtually I just figured out what my problem is... It had to do with my copy data over code.. I thought it was correct it isn't.  I need to update the question.

Comment: Have you tried Mat::copyTo instead of clone? It doesn't answer your question, but perhaps it could be a workaround.

Comment: It turns out that copying over code was wrong.  I had to fix the appropriate StackOverflow question I made in regards to how to copy it over: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754099/working-with-monochrome-qimage

Answer (score 6):

I had a heap corruption... general rule of thumb for me from now on... If cv::Mat is segfaulting, I corrupted the heap somewhere.

Edit: By "somewhere", I meant you can safely assume that cv::Mat is correct and that the functions it uses are correct. You can safely assume that YOU are corrupting memory somewhere on your own, probably at one of your pointers or data structures.

Comment: @Constantin: could you please explain about heap corruption....i am facing the same segmentation fault during `copyTo()` and `clone()`

Comment: The corruption was on another data structure, which translated to corrupting the allocated memory in the cv::Mat. Your problem lies in code not related to the cv::Mat, but somewhere where you're dealing with pointers/dynamic memory.